# Writing custom log files in Databricks Repos using the logging package

Tags: python, logging, databricks, azure-repos

I would like to capture custom metrics as a notebook runs in Databricks. I would like to write these to a file using the logging package. The code below seems to run fine but it never writes to file. How do you achieve this in Databricks runtime 9.1?

Also note that I am running this is Repos so I have to explicitly write it to a location. Furthermore this code runs perfectly fine when run from my workspace.

```
logger = logging.getLogger('server_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
fh = logging.FileHandler('/dbfs/tmp/my_log.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.warning(f'starting to log the process')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I was using a relative filename to show that the chosen filename was the problem (whether due to non-existence or lack of write permission) - I wasn't suggesting that you use a relative filename in your production environment.

Comment: So the problem is not the filename now as this code actually runs fine from my Workspace - I will update the question again - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the `/dbfs/tmp` directory doesn't exist, or you don't have write access to it. Changing the log filename to just `mylog.log`, it works as expected:

```
~/SO-logging-misc$ python so_74519222.py
~/SO-logging-misc$ more my_log.log 
2022-11-21 14:33:22 - WARNING - starting to log the process
```

Comment: you have the right reason - OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported - the logging module cannot write to the location but it does exist. However I am running this in Repos so I cannot write to a relative location - I will update the question with this info.